# Was Nimona replaced as a child, or possessed?

Tags: graphic-novel, nimona

In the original graphic novel - disregarding the the later animated feature film - [Nimona's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nimona) "true" origin story as told during flashbacks midway through the book appears to draw on the European tradition of the Changeling. Suggesting that the original Nimona died as a child and was replaced by a Changeling child that took on her form, or that she was spirited away by a Changeling and replaced with a Changeling child.

In effect, the Nimona that we follow through the story was always a magical creature imitating a human, and never was a human child.

Later on in the story Nimona is split into two components. One taking the form of a human child and one of a monster. Both appear to have their own independent minds and personalities, and which can lead (at least for a period of time) separate lives.

This suggests that rather than being replaced as a child Nimona was a human who was possessed by a magical creature.

Has the author ever clarified Nimona's true nature (Was she possessed or replace, or a third option), for example, during a panel event or book signing?